# Can't install latest version of R on ARM Chromebook

Tags: r, crouton

So I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 through Crouton, and every time I install R it only installs v3.0.2. I've tried reinstalling it, using PPA, and other things but nothing's worked so far.

Comment: Searching through [the R-Dev ppa](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/rdev?field.series_filter=trusty) it seems that there is in fact a build for both armhf and amd64 architectures for v3.2.4 on trusty. I don't know what running in a chroot is doing to apt (if anything), could you post the output of `$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to make sure the ppa is added correctly?

Comment: [This](https://bpaste.net/show/0cfdcbdffca4) is the output I got from it - does it seem right?

Comment: Yeah, that should be it. So the commands `$ sudo apt update` and `$ sudo apt install r-base --reinstall` don't work?

Comment: Nope - I always get [this](https://bpaste.net/show/efb0abe0be8c) instead.

Comment: Have you tried the classic combination of 
`$ sudo apt autoremove`
`$ sudo dpkg --configure -a`
`$ sudo apt install -f`

Comment: It's still at 3.0.2 :(

Comment: What happens with installing/reinstalling each of the declared dependency packages on their own? I'm really baffled by the `apt` manifest not pulling the newer version packages from the ppa repositories.

Comment: everything works fine right up until r-base, at which point the same error (r-base-core's not new enough) appears each time

Comment: Uh-oh, I wonder if you have an ARM computer; double checking the package manifests for armhf [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/) (by downloading the `packages.gz` file and viewing it) I see there is no list for `r-base-core` v3.2.4, while the other dependency packages are listed. Indeed, under the `amd64` build tree package list, there are both `r-base-core` and `r-base-core-dbg` which are conspicuously missing from the `armhf` manifest. Could you please post the output of `$ uname -a` to confirm your install architecture? I'll file a bug if so

Comment: [here's](https://bpaste.net/show/67e6fae124da) my output

Comment: I've sent a message to Michael (the R-Dev ppa maintainer)

Answer (score 1):

I have quite bad news: in this case, where the packages are broken for your architecture, the PPA maintainer said that it was unlikely the irregularities would be fixed any time before June. He's off on vacation, and said that "R-dev is really only for making sure development releases are building and working, and are not designed to be used for anything other than that".

However, there is an even newer version of R out, v3.3.0, and it is a fairly straight-forward installation from source code. I have here step-by-step instructions for installing from source working in a terminal, which you seem comfortable enough with and probably don't need, but for the sake of a more complete answer. The `.deb` files available from the r-project site seem only to be of `i386` and `amd64`, so building it yourself seems to be the way forward.

First download the source code:

```
aich@compy:~$ cd Downloads/
aich@compy:Downloads$ wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.3.0.tar.gz
```

Then expand the compressed archive file and move to the build directory with:

```
aich@compy:Downloads$ tar -xvf R-3.3.0.tar.gz
aich@compy:Downloads$ cd R-3.3.0/
```

This source package doesn't have all of the resources you will need to build the language; also it does require that we resolve the dependencies ourselves. I've made a laundry list here, starting with a bare new VM of Ubuntu Desktop:

```
aich@compy:R-3.3.0$ sudo apt install build-essential gfortran libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev liblzma-dev libpcre3-dev libpng12-dev libreadline-dev libtiff5-dev libx11-dev libxt-dev zlib1g-dev
```

This list of packages should be 100% the same for your `armhf` install of Ubuntu as my `amd64`, but I was building on 16.04 rather than 14.04 (sorry didn't have a downloaded iso ready-to-go for the VM). These packages contain library extensions to the default languages on the Ubuntu install (for building new programs that can use compression, https, etc). If you are curious about what they are, query any entry with `$ apt show <package name>` and it will provide a short description. This is not every possible library for R, but the minimum required to have basic functionality. Now we check to see if we have all the libraries we need and if they are a new enough version:

```
aich@compy:R-3.3.0$ ./configure
                      (... whole bunch of ouput from Autotools checks ...)
```

If it stops without nice output like this:

```
R is now configured for <your arch here>-pc-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /usr/local

  C compiler:                gcc  -g -O2
  Fortran 77 compiler:       f95  -g -O2

  C++ compiler:              g++  -g -O2
  C++11 compiler:            g++  -std=c++11 -g -O2
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:         

  Interfaces supported:      X11
  External libraries:        readline, curl
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, TIFF, NLS
  Options enabled:           shared BLAS, R profiling

  Capabilities skipped:      cairo, ICU
  Options not enabled:       memory profiling

  Recommended packages:      yes
```

... then stop, and read the error above the command prompt carefully. Consider, again carefully, if having v3.3.0 instead of v3.0.2 is worth the trouble (I have no idea what the feature improvements are at all). Track down the missing dependency with a little apt-fu `$ apt search <thing that seems to be missing>`. But if it works, and I believe it should, build and install the software:

```
aich@compy:R-3.3.0$ make -j4
( ... a whole ton of output from GCC ... )

aich@compy:R-3.3.0$ sudo make install -j4
```

Hopefully that should be all you need to do. To get into the REPL, type `$ R` and away you go.

Comment: I wasn't able to get 3.3.0, but I did manage a 3.2.4. Thanks a ton!